# Getting error while integrating Redis with ASP.Net core 6: Wrong number of args calling Redis command From Lua script

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redis, lua

I was trying to implement distributed caching using Redis Cache in ASP.Net core 6. Followed the below urls:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/distributed-redis-caching-in-asp-net-core/
https://medium.com/net-core/in-memory-distributed-redis-caching-in-asp-net-core-62fb33925818

But getting this exception on SetAsync() command ->  "error_description": "ERR Error running script (call to f_3915ee22fda531a1d5661f2523d0443fd35ff0a4): @user_script:2: @user_script: 2: Wrong number of args calling Redis command From Lua script "

1)Installed Redis(3.0.504) locally ( https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/releases)
2)I have installed Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis package
3)My AddAsync method:

```
public async Task AddAsync(string key, byte[] value)
{
    // Setting up the cache options
    DistributedCacheEntryOptions options = new DistributedCacheEntryOptions()
        .SetAbsoluteExpiration(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5))
        .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));

    await _distributedCache.SetAsync(key, value, options, token);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to the version of `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis`.

**Github Issues:**

[Receiving error when invoking IDistributedCache.SetAsync: Wrong number of args calling Redis command From Lua script #39879](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39879)

**Summary:**

We can reproduce the issue easily and the good news the latest version has fixed this issue.

So I suggest you can use `.net 6` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis 6.0.2`.

Comment: Thanks!!! Jason Pan, I upgraded my Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis package version and it is working fine now.